# racket cover gets overwritten if I execute more than one set of tests

Tags: racket

I am trying to measure coverage with racket cover

https://docs.racket-lang.org/cover/basics.html

like this

```
raco cover hello.rkt
```

However, if I run it more than once, it overwrites what is in the coverage directory instead of adding to it.  If I do something like

```
raco cover hello.rkt
raco cover bye.rkt
```

the two html reports specific to these rkt files (coverage/hello.html and coverage/bye.html) remain intact, coverage/index.html will only have bye.rkt in it.  Also I guess if they share a library, I'll only get coverage info for that library from the last run.

Does anybody have a way to combine two coverage reports from two different executions?

Comment: I haven't tried, but does `raco cover hello.rkt bye.rkt` work?

Comment: Yeah that totally works! That still won't solve my current problem because of the way these end to end tests work... but it's still great to know

Comment: You could use `raco cover -d ...` to put output into distinct directories.  You'd then need to manufacture a top-level index.

Comment: I guess the problem with that is that if I extract a shared module, and half of it is covered by one of the tests, and have by the other, I half of the coverage will be in one of the report directories, and half in the other.